# html table with titles centered?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have made a html table for a form..

but for each section of the form I want a title that spans the entire width of the table e.g. "Quick search", "Advanced search" that spans the entire row length of the table

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MHtvq/3/

But there's a problem: The text "Quick search" or "Advanced search" can't really be centered. Because they are situated in one column of the table.

```
       <tr height= "100px" >
                        <td bordercolor="#90DBFF" bgcolor="#CC99CC" style="left-padding:20px">Quick Search</td>
                        <td bordercolor="#90DBFF" bgcolor="#CC99CC"></td>

       <tr>
```

What I want is this (see the red text in the ugly picture):
[image: table]

Is there another way around this? Should I use multiple tables and then divs as the title?

I'm not sure of the best way to approach this..

Comment: Look into using the `<th>` tag and the `colspan` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a table cell span multiple columns by adding colspan attribute to the cell. something like this:

```
<td colspan="2">quick search</td>
```

you should also use css for styling (the border color and background color properties)

Answer (score 1):

set

```
<td style="text-algin=center">
```